# Understanding API Resource Conditionals

Tags: laravel, inertiajs

I'm building an API resource and need help understanding the conditional logic.

Below is the resource:

```
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            $this->when(Auth::user()->type === 'sos', [
                'code' => $this->name,
                'ctds' => $this->ctds,
                'address' => $this->address,
                'city' => $this->city,
                'state' => $this->state,
                'zip' => $this->zip,
                'name' => $this->name,
                'phone' => $this->phone,
                'url' => $this->url,
                'deleted_at' => $this->deleted_at,
            ]),
        ];
    }
}
```

the condition is true with the following:

```
class SfasController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        
        return SfaResource::collection(Sfa::query());
}
```

But false with the below:

```
class SfasController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        

      return Inertia::render('Sfas/Index', [
       'sfas' => SfaResource::collection(Sfa::query()
        ->orderBy('name')
        ->paginate(10)
        ->withQueryString()),
        'filters' => Request::all('search', 'trashed'),

    ]);
```

SFA Route List:

```
GET|HEAD | sfas                                   | sfas                  | App\Http\Controllers\SfasController@index                        | web                                         |
|        |          |                                        |                       |                                                                  | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate            |
|        | POST     | sfas                                   | sfas.store            | App\Http\Controllers\SfasController@store                        | web                                         |
|        |          |                                        |                       |                                                                  | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate            |
|        | GET|HEAD | sfas/create                            | sfas.create           | App\Http\Controllers\SfasController@create                       | web                                         |
|        |          |                                        |                       |                                                                  | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate            |
|        | PUT      | sfas/{sfa}                             | sfas.update           | App\Http\Controllers\SfasController@update                       | web                                         |
|        |          |                                        |                       |                                                                  | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate            |
|        | DELETE   | sfas/{sfa}                             | sfas.destroy          | App\Http\Controllers\SfasController@destroy                      | web                                         |
|        |          |                                        |                       |                                                                  | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate            |
|        | GET|HEAD | sfas/{sfa}/edit                        | sfas.edit             | App\Http\Controllers\SfasController@edit                         | web                                         |
|        |          |                                        |                       |                                                                  | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate            |
|        | PUT      | sfas/{sfa}/restore                     | sfas.restore          | App\Http\Controllers\SfasController@restore                      | web                                         |
|        |          |                                        |                       |
```

I have no idea why. Can you explain?

Comment: Most likely related to route, can you show the routes from the output of php artisan route:list for the two given routes in question

Comment: I just added them to the post. I'm very new and wasn't sure which two routes you needed. I'm assuming the Index route. Please let me know if you need more. And thank you!!